# Which way to use HttpClientFactory is better?

Tags: asp.net-core, httpclientfactory

I am developing a web api service using ASP.NET Core and i need to do http requests. I read a lot about HttpClient and I know i have to use HttpClientfactory instead. I'm going to incapsulate http request calls into my custom class.

I expect a relatively large number of client requests and i try to understand which way is better in terms of performance (two examples attached)?

I like second way more because i can use this into static class but i'm not sure about performance.

```cs
// IHttpClientFactory registration
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 services.AddHttpClient();
}


// my first way (dependency injection into custom class)
public class CustomClass
{
  private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
  public CustomClass(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
   {
     _clientFactory = clientFactory;
   }
}

// my second way
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection().AddHttpClient().BuildServiceProvider();
var httpClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
```

Comment: The first way. The second way is functionally the same as just doing `new HttpClient()` every time, only with a lot more cruft and memory utilization. The whole principal of `IHttpClientFactory` is that it lives for the life of the application, so that it can actually hold on to and distribute instances of `HttpMessageHandler`. With the second bit of code, it goes away immediately.

Answer (score 2):

### Your first way is correct.

```cs
public class CustomClass
{
  private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
  public CustomClass(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
   {
     _clientFactory = clientFactory;
   }
}
```

In that way, you allow dependency injection to resolve the `IHttpClientFactory` service without much effort from your side. The DI container exists throughout the life of your application and handles the creation of various services - for example it [keeps the factory](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/HttpClientFactory/Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L36) ready to provide instances of `HttpClient` when requested. Sleek, swift and safe. The services' configuration occurs only once - at application startup.

#### Second way

You second way would allocate quite a lot of unnecessary new objects (which consume more RAM) when under - as you said - *"a relatively large number of client requests"*. That's because you are basically doing what IoC container would do, but by hand and with noticeable overhead. Assuming that you would not use this code in a singleton, but in a scoped or transient service (see difference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#service-lifetimes)), then with every incoming request you would create service collection, add required services, create a service provider, try to resolve the factory and eventually create a `HttpClient`.

In your first way you only do the last two steps - resolve the factory and create new `HttpClient`. All other is handled by DI.

### The bakery

Imagine owning a bakery. Every day hundreds of clients come by. They all request known delicacy - your famous brownie. In order to be able to produce enough cake you came up with two methods of production:

#### Way #1

You start your day before opening the bakery and make arrangements - you clean the dishes, warm up the ovens, you prepare bowls and ingredients for the dough etc. When it's time to open, you are ready and you can start creating lots of brownie on the fly because everything in your bakery is at hand.

#### Way #2

You start your day coming to the bakery at the time to open. You make no preparations. Only when a client appears, you start to heat up the ovens, gather bowls and ingredients - all this so you can make a single brownie. When you are finished you put back all the stuff back at its place, turn off the ovens, even when you can see that there is a long queue just before your bakery. When the next client approaches - you start the process once again.

#### Conclusion

I hope you can see better performance of the first way. Of course, the second way of bakery example is indecently exaggerated, but it's just to show a greater contrast.

Creating a service provider on your own is not a bad thing. You just need to have a solid reason to do it, for example database seeding or unit/integration testing.

Comment: Prolog, thank you very much for the detailed answer and an understandable example about bakery! I'm going to use first way and i want to incapsulate some code in another class. Is it correct to pass an instance of an IHttpClientFactory as a parameter to the method of another class or there is another way to do this?

Comment: I mean a static class (without constructor).

Comment: I deliberately omitted answering to your static or no-static dilemma because whether to combine `Httpclient` and static state is a perfect material for another question, which goes beyond my knowledge and experience giving me right to post an answer. Generally `HttpClient` is designed to be reusable but it is not just that simple. In play comes sockets, DNS and other matters. IMHO static code is okay as long it stays stateless, see [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/161222) and [that](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/232865) questions about static code.

Comment: Prolog thank you very much, you really helped!